# Is the compound optically active?

Tags: stereochemistry

My work -
The compound seems to have a plane of symmetry(POS)(The plane of the compound itself seems to be the POS)
Because- all carbon atoms in the benzene ring, the - COOH, the C=C, are all SP2 which means they are all planar.

The CH3's may be oriented so that the 2 H is in the plane, 1 H above, and 1 below - meaning, they are symmetric about the plane.

So I concluded that it is optically inactive but the answer states that it is indeed optically active.
Where am I wrong?
Thank you in advance
[image: The compund in question]

Comment: This compound sure would "like" to be flat, but is it able to be?

Comment: Won't the Br being large  try to avoid the CH3 and so become out of plane along with the rest of the group.